# why does it give a nullinjectionError?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular16

I'm pretty sure this code worked before, but now it doesn't work since the last angular update.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { UserModel } from "../Models/UserModel";
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, retry } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  rootUrl = "";

  Login(email: string, password: string): Observable<number> {
    let Param1 = new HttpParams()
      .set("email", email)
      .append("password", password);
    console.log("These are Params:  " + Param1);
    return this.http.get<number>(this.rootUrl + "/U/GetUser", {
      params: Param1,
    });
  }

  CreateUser(user: UserModel) {
    this.http
      .post(this.rootUrl + "/U/CreateUser", user)
      .subscribe((res) => alert("User Created" + user));
  }
}
```

I tried some other methods of dependency implementation, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're either missing the `HttpClientModule` in your `NgModule` or the `provideHttpClient` provider in your providers config at the root of your app.